# ProductLicense status is incorrect in Windows 10 app

Tags: windows-10

I am observing two problems with product license (in-app purchase) in my Windows 10 app.

The first is that some of my clients complain about loss of their purchase. I carefully verified the app logic about it and I am sure that I have all necessary precautions against variety of situations: no-network connection, exceptions, etc. In all suspicious cases my app assumes that the user purchased the product, so I am sure that it is incorrect result of ProductLicense.IsActive property (becoming false inappropriately). ExpirationDate cannot be a problem because duration of my product is indefinite. The app works fine for thousands of users, but fails for a few (about ten). The number of failures is not high, but it really hurts their experience (and the app's reputation).

The second problem I noticed myself was opposite. On one of my development computers (SurfaceBook) I started noticing that ProductLicense.IsActive=true - even though I never purchased my own product from this account - I don't even have any payment means on that account. In debugger I see that IsActive property is "true" after getting it from Windows. The behavior is absolutely persistent on that computer, while my other computers with the same account report expected IsActive=false.

I suspect that these two problems are the two sides of the same unknown cause.

My jscript code for checking the license information is quite simple:

```
var currentApp = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp;
var licenseInfo = currentApp.licenseInformation;
var isProductPurchased = licenseInfo.productLicenses.lookup("MyProduct").isActive;
```

I also tried equivalent code implemented in C# - with the same results.

Is it only me who face this problem? Is there a work around? Please help with an advice. Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you have any progress on it?